# How to get current time for a given timezone in hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have 2 tables in Hive.

table1 contains

```
timelocation
2015-03-04 15:00 Chicago
2015-03-04 15:00 Denver
2015-03-04 15:00 Honolulu
```

table2 contains

```
ID                       Description
America/Chicago          CENTRAL STANDARD TIME                              
America/Denver           MOUNTAIN  STANDARD TIME                            
Pacific/Honolulu         HAWAII-ALEUTIAN STANDARD TIME
```

For a record present in table1 say "2015-03-04 15:00 Chicago" , I need to do a lookup in table2 for the corresponding Chicago record. It should read the ID & Description for chicago and return the current Central Standard Time for Chicago i.e "2015-05-04 09:11".

Similarly for Denver it must return Mountain Standard Time &  for Honolulu it must return HAWAII-ALEUTIAN STANDARD TIME.

Expected output is

```
timelocation
2015-05-04 09:11
2015-05-04 08:11
2015-05-04 04:11
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really want to write this query for you but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.  You need to join `tbl1 <=> tbl2`.  Extract the city from the respective columns in each table; `split()` function will help you.  Then there is a nifty function you can find [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) called `from_utc_timestamp()` that takes a time stamp (assumed to be UTC) and converts it to a given time zone.  You'll also need to convert the column `Description` to its time zone abbreviation.  You can find those [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the **table1** and **table2** using the following query:

```
SELECT T1.timelocation,T2.ID,  T2.Description, to_utc_timestamp(SUBSTRING(T1.timelocation,1,16),T2.ID) AS newtime
FROM table 1 T1 INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON SUBSTRING(T1.timelocation,17)= SUBSTRING(regexp_extract(T2.ID,'/\w*',2),2)
```

Here output of the regex function on let's say `America/Chicago` will be `/Chicago` , therefore I am doing a substring on the output to extract `Chicago` and match to the Substring of `timelocation` column.

For more info about the hive regex function `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)` check the  [@Hive Doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: `substring(regexp_extract())` is overkill.  Just use `split([str], '\\/')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    to_utc_timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00','PST')

returns 2015-01-01 08:00:00