# How to extract characters to the right of a delimited value in a SELECT statement in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to extract all the characters to the right of a "/" as part of a select statement.

```
city

America/Chicago

Europe/London
```

Expected output is

```
cityname

Chicago

London
```

This is my query which is not working

```
select substring(city, charindex('/',city) +1, length(city)) as cityname from table;
```

Comment: The answer to this question can be found [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032713/how-to-get-current-time-for-a-given-timezone-in-hive/30074038#30074038)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to extract city name. Using regular expression your query will be like this.

```
select regexp_extract(city, '([a-zA-Z]+)', 1) from table_name;
```

where `regexp_extract()` is a record/line extraction of the data you wish to extract. More detail about `regexp_extract()` is available on hive [LanguageManual+UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Regular expression tutorial is available on this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

**UPDATE1**

Input Data:

```
Hello/Chicago
101/London
By/America
```

Query and regular expression to extract everything after `/`:

```
select regexp_extract(city,'.*\/(.*)',1) from tbl_name;
```

Output:

```
Chicago
London
America
```

Comment: Using this query, I got desired output. Can you share your current query.

Comment: I am getting the output America Europe. But I want the output to be Chicago London

Comment: The regular expression I am using that extract character from given data. But I see you have modified your input data then you need to modify your regular expression. You need to work on regular expression part in the query.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I have edited it. I want to extract the value whatever I get after '/'.

Comment: Ok. then you have to make a regular expression which can extract data after '/' only. Need to go deep into regular expression pattern :)

Comment: It's bit late, but still I have updated my answer as per your comment. :)